# Can I get the touch coordinates without using listener?

Tags: android

Is there any way to get the coordinates of touch (when user touch/multi-touch on activity) without using the OnTouchListener event ? If it is possible, then kindly provide me any example.

Comment: Your question is like I want to drink beer but dont wannna buy it

Comment: lol you should try [washing your phone](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/15?m=938932#938932)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
int x, y;
TextView tv, tl;
FrameLayout fl;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText("X Coordinate");

    tl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.touchView);
    tl.setText("Y Coordinate");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    x = (int) e.getX();
    y = (int) e.getY();
    tv.setText("" + x);
    tl.setText("" + y);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jignesh for reply. When i touch the view (R.Layout.main) at runtime, call never comes in onTouchEvent. Should we need to register onTouchEvent to view? Or am i missing something ? I have activity whose contentview is set to R.layout.main.

Comment: public class TouchTestAppActivity extends Activity            {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.touch);
        View view = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

     }
    
    public boolean OnTouchEvent( MotionEvent e )
     {
     //return gestureScanner.OnTouchEvent( e );
     String test = "hello";
     test = "kk";
     return true;
     }